# How to insert an embedded link in text on a facebook Status Update

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, status

Suppose I wanted to post something and give a link of a facebook page (suppose take it "Hello"). I just want an status update which will contain a link(a text link, which is similar to other links) which on click will redirect to my facebook page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can used this code to post status:

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=2915120374&display=touch&method=stream_publish&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com&async&action_links=[{"text":"máy đo đường huyết","href":"your url"}]&attachment={'media':[{'type':'image','src':'#','href':'http://www.maydoduonghuyet.com.vn/'}],'description':'','properties':{'Click+':{'text':'máy đo đường huyết','href':'your url'}}}
```